# How to use equal operator in where clause with date column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the following query to retrieve the data from database but i am getting this throwing :
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Here is my query

```
Select * from employees where req_date =TO_DATE('05-18-2014','MM-dd-yyyy');
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this error.

Comment: What type of column is req_date? If it is a date column you should use `TO_DATE` instat of `TO_CHAR`

Comment: Type of req_date is Date.

Comment: @Zaheer: TO_DATE('18-05-2014','dd-MM-yyyy') is exactly the same date as TO_DATE('05-18-2014','MM-dd-yyyy')

Comment: You query looks perfectly ok. Are you absolutely sure the req_date is DATE column? You can verify this with: `select data_type
from user_tab_columns where upper(table_name)='EMPLOYEES' and upper(column_name)='REQ_DATE';`

Comment: Your query running successfully for me. If it is not for u then just alter your session like "alter session set nls_date_format ='MM/dd/yyyy';" and then try your query.

Comment: @Kitezzz: Why would that be necessary. nls_date_format plays no role when comparing dates with dates.

Answer (score -1):

You Can Convert the `date` into `Varchar` and then use, like below

```
Select * from employees where Convert(Varchar,req_date,112)='20140518'
```

The above query may help you....

Comment: The Oracle convert function converts data from one characterset to another. It has nothing to do with date conversion.

Comment: -1 for the wrong syntax of CONVERT function. [CONVERT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620) changes character set not datatype